# Delete image from database and from folder in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I try to delete an image from database and from folder, image path is saved in the database when we create a post, when  e`cho $res = $row['image'];` i got this result
`/bp_project/admin-bp/job/ad_images/Picture3.jpg` , Every thing is fine and record gets deleted from the database but the image is still in 'ad_images' Folder.
if i try u`nlink("ad_images/"."Picture3.jpg");` its working but we didn't need this, we want to delete image by fetching image path from database.
Anybody can help me delete image by fetching image path from database Thanks.

```
$user_email=$_SESSION['session_email_id'];
$token=$_GET['id'];

$result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM bp_users WHERE email= '".$user_email."'");
$result->execute();
$row = $result->fetch();
$user_token = $row['token_id'];

if(isset($token)){
    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM job WHERE token_id = '".$token."'");
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();

    echo $res = $row['image'];

    if(file_exists($res)){

        unlink($res);

        $result = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM job WHERE token_id= :memid");
        $result->bindParam(':memid', $token);
        $result->execute();

        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Ad Successfully Deleted!')</script>";
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.open('all-ad.php?user_token=".$user_token."','_self')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Ad not Deleted Please Try Again!')</script>";
        echo "<script language='javascript' 
        type='text/javascript'>window.open('all-ad.php?
        user_token=".$user_token."','_self')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with the absolute path to delete the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but we didn't need this, we want to delete image by fetching image
>   path from database.

if you want to delete it by fetching image path from the database then you need to store absolute path in your database.

Instead of storing complete path in the database just store the image name and use it with absolute path to delete.

Then you can use unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'image_name_from_db'); to delete it

Answer (score 0):

All you need Is to Delete the image from database so if you want to delete from database you can use "Delete" Key word Or what Please make it clear!